# How to get distribution for each participant

Tags: r, group-by

I am trying to fit the **inverse gaussian distribution** to each participant's response times to get the mu and lambda of the distribution for each participant. However, even though I tried many ways of doing it, it always gives me the same output for all participants instead of fitting the distribution to each participant individually.

I have tried the following:

```
  library(goft)
  require(stats)
  by(Data, Data[,"Participant"], function (x) ig_fit(Data$RT)))
```

output

```
 Data[, "Participant"]: P001G01S01
        Inverse Gaussian MLE 
 mu                  448.8195
 lambda             6486.4473
```

---

```
Data[, "Participant"]: P002G01S02
        Inverse Gaussian MLE 
 mu                  448.8195
 lambda             6486.4473
```

---

```
Data[, "Participant"]: P003G02S01
      Inverse Gaussian MLE 
 mu                  448.8195
 lambda             6486.4473
```

I would expect the following:

```
Participant  mu        lambda

1            480.252    6005.23
2            521.23     5312.632
3            490.325    6320.53
```

Comment: The output from `by` is a `list`.  You can do `do.call(rbind, by(Data, ...` or with `dplyr` `library(dplyr);Data %>% group_by(Participant) %>% summarise(out = list(ig_fit(RT)))`  It is better to provide a small repro example and also the packages for `ig_fit`

Comment: My problem is that the list is always the same independently of the participant.

Comment: That can be explained because you are calling `Data$RT` instead of `x$RT`. The `Data$RT` is the whole column instead of the split column `by` group

Comment: I thought that could be the issue, just did not find a way to go around it. Would it be Data$Participant$RT? Or is it enough to do Participant$RT? I tried the first one before but did not work.

Comment: As I mentioned, your anonymous function call is `function(x)`.  It is the data now.  so you just need `x$RT`

Comment: just to clarify `Data[,"Participant"]` is the grouping column.  It doessn't have any other column nested inside it

Comment: oh I see, the data looks exactly like the one in the other question. If that helps. I will try these suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @akrun, the minor change worked.

```
  library(goft)
  require(stats)
  by(Data, Data[,"Participant"], function (x) ig_fit(x$RT)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Grouped by 'Participant', apply the `ig_fit` on the 'RT', transpose (`t`) the output, convert it to a `tibble` wihtin in `summarise`, wrap as a `list` (as `summarise` expects an element of length 1 per group as output and `list` is of `length` 1), then `unnest` the `list` to return the data.framee with 3 columns ('Participant', 'mu', and 'lambda')

```
library(tidyverse)
library(goft)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  summarise(out = list(ig_fit(RT) %>% t
                                  %>% as_tibble)) %>%
  unnest(out)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Participant    mu lambda
#        <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1           1  460. 10720.
#2           2  472.  5272.
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Participant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), RT = c(352L, 526L, 624L, 424L, 356L, 475L, 256L, 
426L, 562L, 426L, 526L, 634L), Session = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Testing_Condition = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```