# how to subset data based on two variables

Tags: r, select

I have a dataset that looks like this (it's in long format because of `R`):

```
 Participant      RT     Session    Testing_Condition
     1            352       1               0
     1            526       1               0
     1            624       1               0
     1            424       2               0
     1            356       2               0
     1            475       2               0
     2            256       1               1
     2            426       1               1
     2            562       1               1
     2            426       1               0
     2            526       2               0
     2            634       2               0
```

And I want to select only the participants with `Testing_Condition = 0` on both sessions. I know how to do subsets, I just do not know how to make sure that the subset does not contain participants that were in `condition = 0` in one session but not in another. Should I create a third variable that is the junction of their overall `testing_condition` or something? If so, how should I go about doing it?

In this case I would expect the output to be the selection of `participant 1` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Participant) %>%
     filter(any(Testing_Condition[Session ==1]== 0) & 
           any(Testing_Condition[Session ==2] == 0))
```

---

it could also be

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Participant, Session) %>% 
   filter(all(Testing_Condition == 0)) %>% 
   group_by(Participant) %>%
   filter(all(1:2 %in% Session))
```

Comment: This is very nice, did not find this anywhere. It makes a lot of sense coming from Python. Can you help with another question? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361697/how-to-get-distribution-for-each-participant"

Comment: @CatM. Thanks, I commented on the posst

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the groups with `any` value with `Testing_Condition == 1`.

To do that in base R, we can use `ave`

```
df[with(df, !ave(Testing_Condition == 1, Participant, FUN = any)), ]

#  Participant  RT Session Testing_Condition
#1           1 352       1                 0
#2           1 526       1                 0
#3           1 624       1                 0
#4           1 424       2                 0
#5           1 356       2                 0
#6           1 475       2                 0
```

Same with `dplyr` can be achieved by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  filter(!any(Testing_Condition == 1))
```